# req.body returns undefined - nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

When I put app.use(bodyParser.json()); **below** app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'))
req.body returns undefined. But if I put app.use(bodyParser.json()); **above** app.use('/api', require('./routes/api')); it returns correctly. So the question is why?

Here is my code:
index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

app.listen(process.env.port || 3000, function(){
    console.log('You are listening to port 3000'); 
});
```

api.js file

```
const express= require('express');
const router= express.Router();

router.get('/ninjas', function(req, res){
    res.send({type: 'GET'});
});

router.post('/ninjas', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send({type: 'POST'});
});

router.put('/ninjas/:id', function(req, res){
    res.send({type: 'PUT'});
});

router.delete('/ninjas/:id', function(req, res){
    res.send({type: 'DELETE'});
});

module.exports =router;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Express remembers the order that middleware (body parser, routers, etc.) are setup, and runs requests through them in that same order. Routes and their handlers aren't automatically deprioritized to processing last.

Answer (score 0):

We need body-parser middleware to read from req.body,

In Javascript code executes line by line (for non IO operations).

So when you place app.use(bodyParser.json()) after requiring your router file logic, body-parser is not invoked and plugged, so you need to invoke it before any other logic, so that you can read from the request.

Answer (score 0):

Bodyparser is a middleware which should run everytime when a route is accessed.
A middleware (like bodyparser) is written like this

```
const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
//some code here
next();
}
```

The `next` function starts the execution of another middleware function

So when you use the `bodyparser` middleware after the routes req.body will not be initialized because the `bodyparser` middleware never ran for the route and the response ends with the `res.send()`.

But if you use the `bodyparser` middleware before initializing the routes the `bodyparser` middleware will always run.

You can see more examples on middleware in the expressjs docs
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html